# garbage value in a 2d array in C

Tags: arrays, c

I am making a program, to check if a number of element in a 2d array is less than the matrix size. And then I have to print how many types of element is less than the matrix size. Strangely, if I make a 3d array, only if I make matrix at the size of 3 x 3 and only at the third "team" get a garbage value.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int matrix_size;
    int team[105];
    int shirt_num = 0;
    scanf("%d", &matrix_size);
    for (int i=shirt_num ; i<matrix_size ; i++){
        team[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i=0 ; i<matrix_size ; i++){
        for (int j=0 ; j<matrix_size ; j++){
            scanf("%d", &shirt_num);
            if (shirt_num <= matrix_size){
                team[shirt_num] += 1;
                printf("team[%d]: %d\n", shirt_num, team[shirt_num]);
            }
        }
    }
    int less_than_matrix_size = 0;
    for (int i=1 ; i<=matrix_size; i++){
        if (team[i] < matrix_size){
            less_than_matrix_size++;     
            
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", less_than_matrix_size);
}

Here is the bugs:
stephenhau@Stephens-MacBook-Pro socs1_problems % cd "/Users/stephenhau/Documents/Learn
ing/Programming_Language/learn_C/socs1_problems/" && gcc Lab7_B_Attendance.c -o Lab7_B
_Attendance && "/Users/stephenhau/Documents/Learning/Programming_Language/learn_C/socs
1_problems/"Lab7_B_Attendance
3
0 0 0
team[0]: 1
team[0]: 2
team[0]: 3
0 0 0
team[0]: 4
team[0]: 5
team[0]: 6
1 2 3
team[1]: 1
team[2]: 1
team[3]: 71687169
2
stephenhau@Stephens-MacBook-Pro socs1_problems % cd "/Users/stephenhau/Documents/Learn
ing/Programming_Language/learn_C/socs1_problems/" && gcc Lab7_B_Attendance.c -o Lab7_B
_Attendance && "/Users/stephenhau/Documents/Learning/Programming_Language/learn_C/socs
1_problems/"Lab7_B_Attendance
4
0 0 0 0
team[0]: 1
team[0]: 2
team[0]: 3
team[0]: 4
0 0 0 0
team[0]: 5
team[0]: 6
team[0]: 7
team[0]: 8
0 0 0 0
team[0]: 9
team[0]: 10
team[0]: 11
team[0]: 12
1 2 3 4
team[1]: 1
team[2]: 1
team[3]: 1
team[4]: 2
4
```

Comment: the rule of the program is that 0 does not count. Only number  other than zero count. And it seems that the problem is in the initialization of the team array, if I make the team array to team[matrix_size + 1], there will be segmentation error. I do not understand why it happens.

Comment: `team[matrix_size]` is uninitialized, you initialize only till `team[matrix_size-1]`

Comment: You are meant to use `i` or `j` index iterators here => `team[shirt_num]`? Because user input is unpredictible and can be larger than max array size which is 105 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here issue is that the array is of size N and you initialize K elements (K<N-1). Now you are trying to access Kth element which is although there but uninitialized, so you are getting some garbage value and not segmentation fault. Try initializing them with 0 and you'll see the desired outcome but it is illegal.

Correct way to do this is

```
            if (shirt_num < matrix_size){
                team[shirt_num] += 1;
                printf("team[%d]: %d\n", shirt_num, team[shirt_num]);
            }
```